# Why are the RouteData Values always empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

I am trying to set my url up as http://localhost/PDM/Welcome/Florida

Where PDM is the virtual directory, Welcome is the home page.
and Florida is the argument passed.

The url seems to be working except I cannot see Florida being passed through.

****updated****

there is no controller.  Visual Studios example...

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new {  action = "Index", id= UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

... was with no controller specified in defaults object.  I used what they had and changed it up a bit, replacing the default page to Welcome instend of Index and Division instead of Index. Division will always be in the url so it seemed to make better since than ID.

I have tried the following.

```
public static class RouteConfig {
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes){
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{division}",
            defaults: new {  action = "Welcome", division = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

2 // and many many other ways

```
// this statement would be a lie there is not controller pdm is the root
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{division}",
            defaults: new { controller="PDM"  action = "Welcome", division = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
// the ideal way
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{division}",
            defaults: new {  action = "Welcome", division = "Florida" }
        );
// and many more not listed
```

I am trying to pull the arguments in on my masterpage.master in the prerender section

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnPreRender(e);

        RouteData rd = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));

        if(rd != null){
            int i = rd.values.Count;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Does that compile? With `int i = rd.values` you're assigning a `RouteValueDictionary` to an `int`.

Comment: yes its compiling.  I aadded the if rd != null for the example.  I updated to values.count.  thanks

Comment: What if you use `HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData`?

Comment: And you probably might want to give the default value for `controller` parameter. As from [this discussion](https://forums.asp.net/t/1995387.aspx?RouteTable+Routes+GetRouteData+is+always+null), ASP.NET might not construct proper route data in case any of the default values is not given.

Comment: yes Request.RequestContext.RouteData would work too.  However values is still empty.
I tried with passing a controller, see updated.

Comment: Well,I don't see any other problem so far. I would suggest to provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that someone could reproduce and debug it.

Comment: its been for ever and never had this issue again with current mvc versions.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a zombie update, but in case any one else comes across it, you might need to call `UseRouting();` in your startup code somewhere. `UseRouting` configures the middleware that populates `RouteData`

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#routing-basics for a bit more info.